# export 'make' (imported as 'PImage') was not found in 'pureimage' (module has no exports)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Expected Behaviour
This was working fine in my Angular 10 project using:

```
import * as PImage from "pureimage"
```

Actual Behaviour
In Angular 16 I get the following error. **However the package actually works as expected.**

> export 'make' (imported as 'PImage') was not found in 'pureimage'
> (module has no exports

)

Steps To Reproduce

```
npm i pureimage
import * as PImage from "pureimage"
const img1: Bitmap = PImage.make(imgFrameWidth, imgFrameHeight, null);
```

I have tried:

```
import { make } from "pureimage";
const img1: Bitmap = make(imgFrameWidth, imgFrameHeight, null);
```

but get the error:

> Error: export 'make' (imported as 'make') was not found in 'pureimage'
> (module has no exports)

Versions:

```
    OS: Windows 10
    Node Version: 16.20.0
    NPM Version: 9.7.6
    PureImage Version: 0.3.17
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": false,
    "noImplicitOverride": true,
    "noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": false,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "ES2022",
    "module": "ES2022",
    "useDefineForClassFields": false,
    "lib": [
      "ES2022",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableI18nLegacyMessageIdFormat": false,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "strictInputAccessModifiers": true,
    "strictTemplates": false
  }
}
```